# GCM wakelock permission

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

After i saw the video from google about performance patterns - [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=orlRuEwlDoM), i decided to implement Google Cloud Messaging.
But while i was implementing GCM for Android, i saw that GCM is using some permissions, and one of them is  "wakelock".
But like we know, this permission is "equals" to battery drain.

So my question is, how we can manage this issue? Lib GCM do this for us?? Is better to use pull notifications than pull?

Thanks

Comment: *But like we know, this permission is "equals" to battery drain.* no, it isn't... It may be true if *we* is equals to *the one who do not know what is going on*

Comment: As we know gcm is using Broadcasts... As we know CPU wakes only on time of onReceive execution ... As we know onReceive should return almost immediately... That's why gcm starts wakeful services GcmListenerService... Which release lock right after onMessageReceived finished... So, battery drain is only up to you. If you will do extremely long operations in onMessageReceived then battery will drain...  If no, then it would run like(almost) there will be no CPU lock at all.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to do it. Google provides a service which handles everything for you. Like below:

```
 public class GcmListenerService extends com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService {

private static final String TAG = "GcmListenerService";

/**
 * Called when message is received.
 *
 * @param from SenderID of the sender.
 * @param data Data bundle containing message data as key/value pairs.
 *             For Set of keys use data.keySet().
 */
// [START receive_message]
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    String message = data.getString("message");
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
    Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);

    if (from.startsWith("/topics/")) {
        // message received from some topic.
    } else {
        // normal downstream message.
    }

    // [START_EXCLUDE]
    /**
     * Production applications would usually process the message here.
     * Eg: - Syncing with server.
     *     - Store message in local database.
     *     - Update UI.
     */

    /**
     * In some cases it may be useful to show a notification indicating to the user
     * that a message was received.
     */
    sendNotification(message);
    // [END_EXCLUDE]
}
// [END receive_message]

/**
 * Create and show a simple notification containing the received GCM message.
 *
 * @param message GCM message received.
 */
private void sendNotification(String message) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TabAllItemsActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, Resources.GCM_NOTIFICATION_REQUEST_CODE, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_notification)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.icon_app))
            .setContentTitle("Message from Faroque")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setColor(R.color.orange_dark)//setting the brand color
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);//This intent will be executed when user tap on it

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(Resources.GCM_NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

}

[Here](https://androidtutorialmagic.wordpress.com/android-service-tutorial/google-cloud-messaging-or-push-notification-in-android/) is a tutorial, you can check if you want. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for answer and tutorial. But that doesnt solve my question about wakelock

Comment: You dont need wakelock. Wakelock is used to activate your CPU if it is in sleep. To do that, you need a broadcast receiver. But this service i gave you, it will handle everything. Run the code from this https://github.com/nanofaroque/GoogleCloudMessagingApp and see how it works like charm. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Defining the wakelock permission does not cause battery drain on its own. Misusing the wakelock does. GcmListenerService manages the wakelock for you which is one of the reasons why using GcmListenerService is a good idea since you don't have to manage the wakelock (which is non-trivial) yourself.